# How to calculate and display large numbers in java

Tags: java

How could I calculate and display all digits of large numbers like `9999!` (factorial of 9999) in java?

Take a look at this [url](http://www.calculatorsoup.com/calculators/discretemathematics/factorials.php) which calculates `9999!` and dislays all digits.

Comment: [BigInteger](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html)

Comment: @JoopEggen BigInteger is SUPER SLOW! :)

Comment: @SarthakMittal but not suboptimally coded. Either use your processors: Java 8 has some nice concurrency options (IntStream parallel), or write to use the GPU, doing array processing.

Comment: @JoopEggen Actually i am trying to promote Strings over here i have made such programs both in Strings and BigInt and the difference between their execution time is HUGE!

Comment: @SarthakMittal do u have any example of using String to calculate Factorial?

Comment: @yaa110 not exactly factorial, but let me tell you something that happened with me, i wrote a code which needed to do many things and also increment a number by 1(yeah just 1) at around 20 places but the problem was that the range was more than 1000 digits of the number so i used BigInteger, the program needed to execute in under 9 secs on the server of the coding site, but i was getting TimeLimitExceeded,then i created a program to add 1 to a number using Strings(it was hardly 20 lines code) so i placed that string code in all of my main program and it got executed in <2.5 secs :)

Comment: @yaa110 i have made a square root program with Strings and BigInt too, but don't get me started on that, but the main thing is that, the difference between their execution time was VERY HUGE(as the size of the input increased)! :)

Comment: @SarthakMittal of course in your case `String` was the best choice, but how could u use it for calculating `factorial`?

Comment: @SarthakMittal i am saying that a user can create a program to multiply two numbers, and when we have that program, it would be very easy to use it to calculate factorials! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use BigInteger; 9999! took 120 ms with Java 8. Here is a version that uses longs, and halves that time:

```
public static BigInteger factorial(int n) {
    // Try first to use longs in calculating the factorial.

    BigInteger result = BigInteger.ONE;
    long factor = 1;
    for (int i = n; i > 1; --i) {
        if Long.MAX_VALUE / factor < i) { // Overflow?
            result = result.multiply(BigInteger.valueOf(factor));
            factor = i;
        } else {
            factor *= i;
        }
    }
    return result.multiply(BigInteger.valueOf(factor));
}
```

Comment: Nice solution with no `StackOverFlow` Exception

Comment: Oh boy, overflow cannot be tested by `factor*i <= factor`. Fortunately the effect on time is still alright. Using `if (Long.highestOneBit(factor) + Integer.highestOneBit(i) > 31) {` unfortunately is more costly.

Comment: `if (Long.MAX_VALUE / factor < i)` would probably be a more readable overflow test.

Comment: I have a theory that I haven't been able to get to work correctly that if you take one high then one low number alternating you reduce the number of overflows, thus total number of BigInteger multiplies.

Comment: I think the logic for alternating is slower than the gain. 1984 multiplies vs 2120.

Comment: @weston The multiplication has as many bits as the sum of bits of both factors. As seen in: 1000 * 100 = 100000. I tried that with highestOneBit. Unfortunately slow. However you are on to something. It might be faster instead of splitting [...][...]...[...] to split [...[...[...]...]...].

Comment: @weston I further reduced the code, but faster it was. Having a precalculated table of factorials would be faster.

Comment: Sure, perhaps using a sparse array of BigInteger, populated lazily. Maybe only storing every 100th n if size is a problem. And calculate from the closest.

Comment: I'm intrigued by the claim that you can do math faster with `StringBuilder`/`char[]` might look at that.

Answer (score 7):

Use BigInteger, his limit is your memory

```
public static BigInteger factorial(BigInteger num) {
    if (num.compareTo(new BigInteger("1")) < 0) {
        return new BigInteger("1");
    } else {
        return factorial(num.subtract(new BigInteger("1"))).multiply(num) ;
    }
}
```

Comment: There is another limit. The call stack. `factorial(9999)` would mean 9999 stack frames. I haven't tried it, and it depends on your stack size, but that's a lot and liable to `StackOverflow`. The solution, as this is tail recursive, is easy - switch to a loop.

Answer (score 4):

The Java standard library provide a `BigInteger` class, which can represent unlimited integer values (actually, they are limited, but only by available memory).

Answer (score 2):

Not the fastest, but not really slow either.

```
public static BigInteger factorial(int n) {
    BigInteger result = BigInteger.ONE;
    for (int i = 2; i <= n; i++) {
        result = result.multiply(BigInteger.valueOf(i));
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Strings (yes don't get astonished, you can!). A program can be created in strings to multiply two very large numbers (here i am talking about numbers say 5000 digits in length, each!)
I have already created them for addition and subtraction and it's not that hard to create it for Multiplication and i assure you that, though you will think that using BigInteger will be faster, but using Strings would be Ultrafast as compared to BigInt.

And the thing that slipped my mid, i used StringBuilder class to make the program more efficient.

Comment: I see, though Strings are immutable like BigInteger too? Do you first use `StringBuilder` or `char[]`?

Comment: lol, yeah you completely got me on that, i used StringBuilder :), sorry for not mentioning, just slipped my mind, let me edit my answer so that people won't get misled :)

Comment: @weston maybe you would be able to find it on the internet, and to tell you the truth i helped a friend of mine to create a program which would multiply two large numbers using only strings, but it was his code initially so it is against my ethics to post that code :)